# Help to find partition on ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Recently when trying to turn on the computer (win 7 64bit) it began to occur the legendary bsod making it to restart over and over. When trying to repair the problem the computer freezes on a black screen or when starting it normally, the blue screen attacks appears again. I took my pc to a shop and they told me that the hard hd (seagate 3tb) is damaged and needs to be replaced. So, after this I booted ubuntu 12:04 via cd and managed to recover the files from c: hd. However, I am not able to locate the partition d: to recover some movies that i had left there. Could anyone tell me how can i access the partition D: from Windows via ubuntu?

Another informations:
a) I do not installed ubuntu, when i try it, this message appears :"No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu." -  Actually i prefer not to install it if possible, because i'm not too familiar with this OS.

I think this is my last shot to recover those files, please help!

Thanks.

Comment: please post gparted screenshot of harddisk. Gparted will be available in Ubuntu cd.

Answer (score 0):

Install ntfs-3g with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`.
Then run the ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition.

> ntfsfix v2.0.0 (libntfs 10:0:0)
>
> Usage: ntfsfix [options] device
>
> ```
> Attempt to fix an NTFS partition.
>
> -h, --help             Display this help
> -V, --version          Display version information
> ```
>
> For example: ntfsfix /dev/hda6
>
> Developers' email address:
>   linux-ntfs-dev@lists.sf.net Linux NTFS
>   homepage: http://www.linux-ntfs.org

=======================================

You can use a program called ntfsprogs.  If its not installed, you can install it by, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
```

Once installed, you need to find out you NTFS drive name, just do `sudo fdisk -`l, to find that out, once you know the name, then

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXX
```

Make sure that you replace the XX with your drive's name.

**Note**: Whenever you're dealing with partition, make sure that you have a complete backup just to be on the safe side.

===================================

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Then run it:

```
sudo testdisk
```

and follow the instructions. You must search for partitions and then write the changes.

Also thanks to answerers here:

- [Fix corrupt NTFS partition without Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows)
- [Repair NTFS without Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330733/repair-ntfs-without-windows)

When you can mount it you can also try:

`sudo dd conv=sync,noerror bs=8k if=/dev/sda6 of=/home/backup-file`

Then you can copy `backup-file` to external drive and later use it to get your saved data.

When later you want do that you would need to mount it, so run:

`sudo losetup /dev/loop1 /home/backup-file`

`sudo mount /dev/loop1 /mnt/backup`